# Unable to send data using pipe to second app which I launched via exec (C++)

Tags: c++, unix, pipe, exec

I have to pass some data from one application to another. I am using pipe for the same. My first application first writes to pipe and then execs second application. But while reading from pipe, it returns nothing.
I am forking a child process, in which I am passing some data using fd[1]. And later I am calling another app using exec.

The code to read data using fd[0] is in the second app. But I am not getting anything. 
**appLaunch.cpp**

```
 int main()
    {
        /*
            This application will send parameters to another application
        */
       int fd[2];
       pid_t childpid;
       char string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
       pipe(fd);
       if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
       {
           perror("fork");
           exit(1);
       }
       if(childpid == 0)
       {
           /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
           close(fd[0]);
           /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
           write(fd[1],string,(strlen(string)+1));
           printf("Starting app...\n");
           execlp("/home/varun/Documents/c programs/C-IPC/app","/home/varun/Documents/c programs/C-IPC/app",NULL);
           exit(0);
       }
       else
       {

       }
       return(0);
    }
```

**app.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
            This application will read parameters from
            calling process from file descriptors
    */
   int fd[2],nbytes;
   pipe(fd);
   close(fd[1]);
    char readbuffer[80];
    /* Read in a string from the pipe */
    nbytes = read(fd[0],readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
    printf("\nReceived string: %s", readbuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got the solution.

I had to open a read pipe in child process of (process that calls another app) `appLaunch.cpp` and write pipe in parent process of `appLaunch.cpp`. And read it via STDOUT in another application i.e. `app.cpp`.
Here is solution code:
**app.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*


            This application will read parameters from
            calling process from file descriptors


    */
  int nbytes;
    printf("\n %s",argv[0]);
    char readbuffer[80];
    /* Read in a string from the pipe */
    nbytes = read(0,readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
    printf("\nReceived string: %s", readbuffer);
    argv[1] = readbuffer;


}
```

appLaunch.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
        /*


            This application will send parameters to another application


        */
      // printf("App Launcher is now live!\n");
       int fd[2], nbytes;
       pid_t childpid;
       char string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
       pipe(fd);
       if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
       {
           perror("fork");
           exit(1);
       }
       if(childpid == 0)
       {
           /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
           close(fd[1]);
           dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
           printf("Starting app...\n");
           execlp("/home/varun/Documents/c programs/C-IPC/app","/home/varun/Documents/c programs/C-IPC/app",NULL);
           exit(0);
       }
       else
       {
           close(fd[0]);
           dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
           write(fd[1],string,(strlen(string)+1));
       }
       return(0);
}
```